# What craftable items reduce radiation in Fallout 4?

Tags: fallout-4

With it easy to get radiated in Fallout 4 and Radaway hard to come by what craftable items are there that reduce your radiation levels?

I'm pretty sure I saw radiation reducing aid/ food mentioned on a loading screen but I've yet to come across anything apart from Radaway to do this.

Comment: You can craft radaway yourself and only need this: Antiseptic (2)
Glowing fungus (3)
Plastic (1)
Purified water (1). I have so much radaway, I'm already selling it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following crafted items provide **rad resistance**:

- Cooking: Baked Bloatfly (+25), Vegetable Soup (+15)
- Chemistry: Glowing Bloodpack (+75)

Mutant Hound Chops **reduces the current radiation** level by 50 and can be crafted from Mutant Hound Meat, which is relatively easy to come by in comparison to frequent RadAway.

Comment: Do they provide rad resistance, or reduce radiation? Those are different.

Comment: As I said, Baked Bloatfly, Vegetable Soup and Glowing Bloodpack increase rad resistance and Mutant Hound Chops reduces radiation level.

Comment: *cough* Radaway *cough* *cough*

Answer (score 1):

At the expense of a little weight, you can add radiation resistance with the "Lead Lined" armor mod. This goes in armor's second mod slot, and requires Armorer 2 and Science 1.

Answer (score 0):

[I found this on Google](http://www.idigitaltimes.com/fallout-4-radiation-system-guide-who-needs-skin-how-radiation-poisoning-kills-you-490210)

Power Armour can be upgraded, which is technically crafting.